# Add a Scala Map into another Scala Map

Tags: scala, collections

I am trying to add a Scala Map object into another Scala Map object.

I've found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995980/map-inside-map-in-scala) but I didn't understand it. I've done some googling but no luck.

I created a test method and need help getting it to run.

**Here is Code:**

```
package com.foo.bar

import collection.mutable.Map
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.Assert;

class FooTest {

  @Test
  def testMap() {

    val row =  Map("fooKey" -> "fooValue", "barKey" -> "barValue")
    var dataToPersist = collection.mutable.Map[String, collection.mutable.Map[String, String]]()
    dataToPersist("fooKey" -> row)
    Assert.assertNotNull(dataToPersist("fooKey"))
    }
}
```

**I get this error while running test:**

```
[ERROR] /Users/app/src/test/scala/com/foo/bar/FooTest.scala:14: error: type mismatch;
[INFO]  found   : (String, scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,String])
[INFO]  required: String
[INFO]     dataToPersist("fooKey" -> row)
[INFO]                            ^
[WARNING] one warning found
[ERROR] one error found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

**Thanks! Here's working code:**

```
package com.foo.bar

import collection.mutable.Map
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.Assert;

class FooTest {

  @Test
  def testMap() {

    val row =  Map("fooKey" -> "fooValue", "barKey" -> "barValue")
    var dataToPersist = Map[String, collection.mutable.Map[String, String]]()

    dataToPersist += "fooKey" -> row

    Assert.assertNotNull(dataToPersist("fooKey"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dataToPersist("fooKey" -> row)
```

is equivalent to

```
dataToPersist.apply("fooKey" -> row)
```

which is the operation used to retrieve an element from the map.

If you want to append an element you can use

```
dataToPersist += "fooKey" -> row
```

but you have to make the type consistent first: `row` is an `immutable.Map` but `dataToPersist` expects `mutable.Map` as values. You need to either make `row` a `mutable.Map` or change the expected type of `dataToPersist`.